# iOS App crashes on button tap in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am very new to Swift. Having a small problem with a IBOutlet button action. When I click the button app crashes. The scenario is as under:

in default ViewController.swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var mv = MyController(nibName:"MyController",bundle:nil);
    self.view.addSubview(mv.view);
}
```

My IBOutlet button is in MyController.swift which loads different .xibs as per device screen size. I have added a button action on MyController as under:

```
@IBAction func test(sender:AnyObject){

    NSLog(" hello ");
}
```

And here is my xib looks like:
[image: MyController view]

Now when I click app crashes. Any clue guys?

[image: App crash screen]

Comment: you probably hooked up the button to the view controller incorrectly. I ran into this issue before. Try deleting the button and the button action method from the view controller and hook them up again by clicking on the button, and then control drag to the outlet

Comment: You shoud hook the @IBAction method in MyController, since button is there. If you want the execution to be handled in MyController, have a delgate.

Comment: @Amit The method is in MyController only.

Comment: The control is not going there?

Comment: Where? The button is there in MyController.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend that you recreate the button in this way

1) Drag your Button to your storyboard. Next, select the Assistant editor at the top right hand corner of Xcode and navigate to your View Controller code.

2) Select Show document outline which is located at the bottom part of your storyboard and click on your button. Next use ctrl click to your code and under connection, select`IBAction`

3) Under that new block of code generated by the IBAction, use `println("Is it working?")` and run it on the iOS Simulator. It should work fine as I tried it on a new project.

Comment: Thanks Wraithseekerr! Here is my Sample Project. Please have a look and correct me.                                                                                                                            http://downloads.ziddu.com/download/24544552/SampleProj.zip.html

Comment: so are you having problems still with the steps I shown you? That website is associated with malware according to google and I'm not going to click on that. Tell me what problems u are having with your code instead of asking me to fix your project.

Comment: Add a new ViewController with a button to Main.storyboard. Now when you click on the button app crashes. That's the issue.

Answer (score -3):

NSLog is Objective-C.  For Swift try this:

```
println("Hello")
```

Comment: I have commented the line NSLog(" hello "); Still app crashes :-(. Any clue?

Comment: Same error, same place?  Control click on **Click Button**, double check where it is connected.

Comment: @CraigSmith NSLog can also be use in Swift.

Comment: That's right Amit. @Craig I have not added a name to UIButton. only hooked the method. If I unlink the method app does not crash. Do I need to maintain a strong relationship with ViewController.swift? Is the problem lies there with ViewController?

Comment: If you add the method to ViewController, it should work.  The only way to get it work in another controller is that the view your button resides must be connected to the class.  If you want the method in MyController, then MyController must be Files Owner for the view the button sits in.

Comment: It works in ViewController. No issues. MyController is File Owner.

Comment: MyController is the Files Owner of MyControll.xib?  Are you sure that you are adding the button to the correct xib?  Where is ViewController.xib?

Comment: Can I send the project? mail me ur id at ranjanchandradey@gmail.com. Must be a silly mistake.